# What does してばかりいる mean?

Tags: syntax

I cannot get 干渉してばかりいる in the sentence below:

私の父はいつも私の私的な生活に**干渉してばかりいる**。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ばかり after a verb ending in -tte or after a noun means "only" or "always", and usually (but not always) has the a negative nuance: in other words, "only interfering (and not letting me just do it without interference)).

In colloquial speech, it's sometimes pronounced/written ばっかり or ばかし.

An example with a noun:

ケーキばかり食べている。 (You only eat cake [nuance: you should eat something else])

Answer (score 3):

[V(て-form)＋ばかり](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A-bakari/) - doing only V

[て＋いる](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-te-iru/) - repeated actions, in the state of doing

> Always meddling in my affairs, always bothering me

Answer (score 0):

The word ばかり has several meanings, one of them is "only".
In your case, it is to emphasize the fact that the father is always interfering.

干渉してばかりいる.
He only interferes. (meaning that he is always interfering)

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/60083/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A/